# upstream packages not showing up in VSTS Package Management

Tags: nuget, azure-artifacts

I've configured the Package Management extension in my VSTS project and added nuget.org as an upstream source.
I've configured my Visual Studio project to use my VSTS feed as the only package source.

I've installed a nuget package from nuget.org via my VSTS feed using `Install-Package` on the Package Manager Console.  I'm expecting the package to then show up in my VSTS feed, but it's not.

Are my expectations wrong, or am I missing a step?

Comment: Are you sure `Install-Package` sourced the package from VSTS and not from NuGet.org? What does the output say?

Comment: @DanielMann Actually it turns out it was pulling it from my local nuget cache, so neither nuget.org nor VSTS.  I didn't think to check that until I read your comment.  Clearing my cache and re-installing the package triggered it to show up in my VSTS feed.  If you want to add an answer I'll accept.

Comment: Add your own answer and accept it, it'll be more helpful for other people than my flailing around in the dark.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had previously installed this nuget package so it was in my local nuget cache.  I cleared the local nuget cache (`Tools->NuGet Package Manager->Package Manager Settings->General->Clear All NuGet Cache(s)`) and re-installed the package, and then saw it pull through my VSTS feed and cache it there.